# Tried to get frame for out of range index NaN react native error

Tags: react-native, expo

I am not so sure why this error is occurring. I have been trying to figure it out but have no idea how. The only thing new about my code is I am using react hooks and declared a state variable called allUsers.

import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { API, graphqlOperation } from 'aws-amplify'

```
  const [allUsers, setAllUsers] = useState([]);

  listQuery = async () => {
    const allUsers = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(listUsers));
    setAllUsers(allUsers);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(allUsers, null, 2));

  };

  useEffect(() => {
    listQuery();
  },[]);

  keyExtractor = (item, index) => index.toString()

  renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <ListItem
      username={item.username}
    />
  )
    return (
      <FlatList
        keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
        data={allUsers}
        renderItem={this.renderItem}
      />
    )


}
```

Comment: Do you actually manage to write data with setAllUsers? And you are not passing anything to renderItem function, there is no item passed

Comment: Sorry can you explain the no item passed to renderItem bc I am fairly new to reactnative

Comment: Will do in an answer

Answer (score 0):

Concerning your renderItem function.

You are passing an item to this function, and when you are using it inside FlatList you are just invoking it, without any item passed.
It should be something like

```
return (
      <FlatList
        data={allUsers}
        keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
        renderItem={({item}) => <this.renderItem item={item}/>}
      />
    )
```

Also, when using functional components, I personally tend to write all my methods as `const`s and then invoke them without any `this`. Should you decide to do this, be aware that your `renderItem` function would be without `this` and you would have to capitalize the first letter, `RenderItem`.

Comment: Wait I applied the following changes but I am still getting the same error

Comment: Are you doing setAllUsers correctly, do you have the correct info, have you tried to log it? Because from the looks of it, you are not setting a plain array in the allUsers state

Comment: Im following the instructions posted in Docs on react hooks and this is the exact syntax

Comment: If I don't know what do you save inside the state, there is not much else I can help with, unfortunately

Comment: I have tried debugging/ console.log to see if my data works and I can see my data in the cosole just not as a FlatList

Comment: The problem with the code is in the data fetch. If `const allUsers` is fulfilled correctly, then it would be a no-brainer - set it in the state as you do and then render flatList using this state. But I am afraid your state of `allUsers` is empty after the fetch, there maybe some parsing missing, but I am not sure.